# How to take only lower-case letters and numbers and put them in separate TextFields?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, keylistener

This class is supposed to take from the keyboard only lower case letters and numbers and put them in separate textfields, however it's adding everything together to the first textfield only!!
What should I do make it work?

```
public class keyEventing extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel ();
JTextField textfield1 = new JTextField ("Numbers");
JTextField textfield2 = new JTextField ("Lower-case letters");

public keyEventing(){
    super("Write Numbers & Lower Case Letters only!");

    add(panel1);
    panel1.add(textfield1);
    panel1.add(textfield2);
    
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout (2,0));
    
    addKeyListener(this);
    
}
@Override 
public void keyTyped (KeyEvent event){
    char c = event.getKeyChar();
    
    if (c > 0 && c < 9)
        textfield1.setText(String.format("%c", c));

    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        textfield2.setText(String.format("%c", c));
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}
```

}

Comment: The digit test needs >= and <= also.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to me. When user gives input to a textfield, he waits his input to take place on the focused textfield, and not in any other next to it. I suggest you to re-consider if you want to do this, in terms of user experience. It is fine if you want only numbers into a textfield and only letters in an other one. I would use a `JSpinner` for the only-numbers textfield, and use a [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) to the one I want only letters.

I mention [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html), because this is the correct way to filter the input given to a text field. A `KeyListener` has many flaws when it comes to text filtering (what if user pastes text? He only pressed Control+V and not the actual keyboard letters). Even if it is possible, it will require much (much) effort to achieve it.

However, if you insist in doing this, here is an example of it (I do not think this is exactly what you are looking for, but I guess its close):

```
public class TextFieldsExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            JTextField onlyDigitsTextField = new JTextField(15);
            JTextField onlyLettersTextField = new JTextField(15);

            AbstractDocument onlyNumbersDocument = (AbstractDocument) onlyDigitsTextField.getDocument();
            AbstractDocument onlyLettersDocument = (AbstractDocument) onlyLettersTextField.getDocument();
            onlyNumbersDocument.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
                @Override
                public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                        throws BadLocationException {
                    //Keep only digits
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    text.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).filter(Character::isDigit).forEach(sb::append);
                    super.replace(fb, offset, length, sb.toString(), attrs);

                    //now "give" letters to only letters textField
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    text.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).filter(Character::isLetter).forEach(sb::append);
                    onlyLettersDocument.insertString(onlyLettersTextField.getText().length(), sb.toString(), attrs);
                }

            });
            onlyLettersDocument.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
                @Override
                public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                        throws BadLocationException {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    text.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).filter(Character::isLetter).forEach(sb::append);
                    super.replace(fb, offset, length, sb.toString(), attrs);

                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    text.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).filter(Character::isDigit).forEach(sb::append);
                    onlyNumbersDocument.insertString(onlyDigitsTextField.getText().length(), sb.toString(), attrs);
                }
            });

            frame.add(new JLabel("Only letters:"));
            frame.add(onlyLettersTextField);

            frame.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(50, 0)));

            frame.add(new JLabel("Only Digits:"));
            frame.add(onlyDigitsTextField);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you're right, but I'm stuck with the  keyListener since it's for a university subject and I must use it. So if you can give an example using it with textfields I would really appreciate it!!

Comment: @NajeeShaheen Your university told you to use a `KeyListener`? Tell your university you found a better way to do it. Also, since it is your homework, I already helped you. You have to do something yourself.